# Xtext: How to get collection type parameter (generics) from JvmTypeReference?

Tags: java, xtext

In Xtext, I am trying to write a utility method to return collection type (generic type) where the collection type is represented by JvmTypeReference created by parser, I need to know the type parameter:

```
@Inject TypeReferences typeReferences;
public JvmType getCollectionType(JvmTypeReference clazz) {
    if (typeReferences.isInstanceOf(clazz, Collection.class)) {
        collectionType = typeReferences.getArgument(clazz, 0);
        return collectionType;
    }
}
```

Example1: for input `java.util.List<String>` I expect the method to return `java.lang.String`, 
Example2: for input `java.util.Set<a.b.m.Book>` to return `a.b.m.Book`.

I need the collection type parameter type for my generator.

The promisingly sounding `typeReferences.getArgument(..)` however returns `JvmParameterizedTypeReference: E` where `getType()` gives `JvmTypeParameter <E> java.util.List`. Hmm. I got into blind alley.

Is it even possible or does the type erasure applies also for `JvmTypeReference`? I hope not.

Thank you for any hints.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. The `getCollectionType()` is correct. What was not correct was the input, the way how I created the `JvmTypeReference`. They did not originated directly from the parsed Model. Only the top level element has explicitly specified type in my DSL. All sub-elements types are inferred using Xtext "introspection", in a cascading manner, from top to bottom. Inferred types are stored in the Model itself; all sorts of other stuff is dependent on them, like validation. To store an inferred JvmTypeReference inside Model AST, one has to make a copy of it.

I did not created the copy correctly. Wrong library call.

Wrong:

```
public JvmTypeReference createDefensiveCopyOfJvmTypeReference(JvmTypeReference typeReference) {
    return typeReferences.createTypeRef(typeReference.getType());
}
```

Correct:

```
public JvmTypeReference createDefensiveCopyOfJvmTypeReference(JvmTypeReference   typeReference) {
    return EcoreUtil.copy(typeReference);
}
```

Well, the `TypeReferences#createTypeRef()` is not entirely wrong. It creates a copy of the desired type but exhibits "type erasure" similar as in Java.

I put this question also on the [Xtext forum](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/991312/).

Check my [DeepCloneDSL](https://bitbucket.org/espinosa/deepclonedsl) project for full source code.

P.S.
Why we have to make a copy of `JvmTypeReference`? And other instances from Xtext common types? `JvmTypeReference` is a complex type, `EObject`, a fragment of AST on its own, a fragment of a model. By setting an attribute of type `JvmType` or similar, one inserts a model fragment to another model; it cannot be inserted twice or be in two different models at the same time. Some of actions such are prevented by Xtext itself, some are more tricky and one has to find [the hard way](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=396433).